# WooCommerce Subscriptions API user_has_subscription() returns nothing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the WooCommerce plugin for Wordpress and trying to make a page that validates the currently logged in user's subscription to a product (Product number 9). The user's subscription status is 'active' but this keeps never returns anything. I'm not sure what's going on or what to try next. The API docs are here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/management-functions/

I'm testing the following code by visiting the page logged in as the user with the active subscription:

```
<?PHP
include('../wp-load.php');
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$SubCheck = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::user_has_subscription($current_user->ID, 9, 'active' );
if($SubCheck)
{
  echo "has sub";
}else
{
  echo "no sub";
}
```

The return value is supposed to be a BOOL.

Comment: The problem is that you are calling [`wp_get_current_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) too early. The Codex references this [trak ticke](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14024) that suggests the way you have called `wp_get_current_user()` might not return the right info, which would then cause the `user_has_subscriptions()` to not work as expected.

Comment: That isn't the problem. This is an external script, not a plugin. $current_user->ID isn't returning the correct number.

Comment: Well then it seems even more likely to be the problem, in my opinion. I'm not sure what you mean by "External script" versus plugin, but if `$current_user->ID` isn't returning a number, then the current user info isn't set up yet since WordPress doesn't do that until the `init` hook.